# Flex: How do I set items to take up MAX 1/3 of their container, unless their content overflows

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's say I have a flex container, I want to be display between 1 and 3 items within.

I would like the items to be:

- By default 1/3 of the width of the container (even if there's only 1 item)
- If one of the item's text content expands slightly beyond the 33% width, I'd like that item to try and expand if it can (i.e. by one of the other items shrinking).
- Justified using flex-start

```css
.container {
  display: 'flex';
  flex-direction: 'row';
  background-color: 'red';
  width: '100%';
  justify-content: 'flex-start';
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: 'no-wrap';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div>
    <div class="item">blahhh</div>
    <div class="item">blahhh</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">I should take up 1/3</div>
</div>
```

The above works for the 3 item case, however when a singular item is placed there it expands to fill the space.

Is this possible?

Comment: `flex:1 1 0;`  on `.item` ?

Comment: Use [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content). I think you might want `stretch`

Comment: `flex:1 1 0; on .item ?` Problem is if there's one item this fills the space. `I think you might want stretch` Sorry I should have added this to the conditions, I want this to be flex-start so that if there are less than 3 items they don't fill the space

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS-Grid for that.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item.wide {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item wide"> I'm wider than 1/3</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanna do it using raw flex though.